# Validating the session using WWW::Selenium

Tags: perl, session, selenium, automation

I am automating a website using `WWW::Selenium` and I am facing an issue.
The code is so written that, the login credentials have to be inputted and then submitted.

But sometimes, the user session is already logged in, resulting in the breakage of the script.

What are the ways by which I can check whether a user session is already active (logged in)?
I know cookie is one way by which session is saved.

But I tried clearing cookies, but still the user was logged in next time.

Please give me some inputs to validate the session.

**EDIT**

I have tried this:

```
if( $sel->is_element_present('id=link-logout') )
```

But it is always returning false. Hope this is the right way, I have to check boolean values?

Answer (score 0):

Does the site have a url that gives a login form even when the user is already logged in?

If not, does it have a logout button or link you can detect and follow?

Selenium isn't going to be able to figure out some magic solution for you; you need to figure out what will work when you are manually operating the browser and then have Selenium do that.

Comment: There is no url which gives login form when user is already logged in. But there is Log out button.

Comment: Check in your browser what the page does when you press the logout button/call the link when you're not logged in. If that doesn't break anything, have Selenium call that link at the beginning of every run and log in a fresh session after that.

Comment: @ysth I am checking for logout link, and it is always returning false.